# Windows Explorer and Updater unstable after plugging a USB device

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, windows-explorer, windows-update

I recently plugged my usual USB key in my computer, but Windows Explorer started to get extremely slow and wouldn't open anything. I tried to check for updates but the Updater stays blank as soon as I click on it. I looked on Microsoft's website for a way to fix that particular issue but the "Fix It" .exe they give get stuck while scanning.

I also did a registry cleanup using CCleaner and rebooted but it's still the same.

I had that issue in the past and the only solution I found then was to boot on the backup partition and wipe everything.

Im'running Windows 7 on an ASUS K53SV.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Thanks.

EDIT : I also noticed that my computer won't shutdown, it gets stuck on the "Closing session" screen. I have to shut it down manually.

Comment: Does the problem go away, as soon as you pull the usb device out?

Comment: provide a xperf trace of the CPU usage: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD Here I can see What in detail Explorer does.

Comment: @VikasGupta No, I have to restart my computer.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The performance toolkit linked in your comment seems to be available for Windows 8 only, I did not find an equivalent for Windows 7.

Comment: the 8.1 SDK version works for Windows7, too.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The setup software stays stuck at 0%.

Comment: which version do you need? 32 or 64Bit?

Comment: @magicandre1981 64

Comment: here is the installer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1bfvldcky5pxsw/WPTx64-x86_en-us.msi?dl=0

Comment: @magicandre1981 Same thing, can't install it.

Comment: what happens? This is the full installer, so it doesn't download anything. Have you disabled the Windows Installer service?

Comment: was the setup now possible?

Answer (score 0):

Open Task Manager (Ctrl-Shift-Esc) and see what processes use CPU time. Try this with and without USB stick to try to find the culprit.
It could be that Windows has lost the driver for the USB device and is looking on the web, but if that were the case, you should see a popup asking to install drivers.
It also could be malware on the USB device... not only Flash RAM, but *any* USB device could host malware, though for other devices than RAM, it is still in proof-of-concept stage.

Comment: I tried it but I didn't notice any changes in the Task Manager.

Comment: One other possibility: I've found that network processes can greatly delay boot time. Is there any difference in time when networking (WiFi, Ethernet etc.) is turned off ("Airplane Mode" for laptops).